# Google Maps. Placing Markers with an interval

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, settimeout

I've been trying to get the code working for hours. It seems to me that everything is ok, but it doesn't work. The markers keep showing up at the same time.

I'd really appreciate if you could point out my mistakes. Thanks in advance!

```
function dropMarker(data){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        title: data.name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        showIW(this);
      });
}


function placeAllMarkers(data){
    clearMarkers();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        setTimeout(dropMarker(data[i]),100*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing a closure to `setTimeout`, you're calling the `dropMarker` function and passing its result to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function to setTimeout not call the function in it. Try

```
function placeAllMarkers(data){
    clearMarkers();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        setTimeout((function(i){return function(){dropMarker(data[i])};})(i),100*i);
    }
}
```